# PHPmyadmin install not working on windows10 local

Tags: phpmyadmin, composer-php

I have tried several installs and PHPMyAdmin is still showing this error message when I goto phpmyadmin/index.php:

> PHP 7.2.5+ is required.
>
> Currently installed version is: ' . PHP_VERSION . ' '); } //
> phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects define('PHPMYADMIN', true); //
> phpcs:enable require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/constants.php'; /** *
> Activate autoloader */ if (! @is_readable(AUTOLOAD_FILE)) { die( '
>
> File ' . AUTOLOAD_FILE . ' missing or not readable. ' . '
>
> Most likely you did not run Composer to ' . '' . 'install library
> files. ' ); } require AUTOLOAD_FILE; Common::run();
> Routing::callControllerForRoute(Common::getRequest(),
> Routing::getDispatcher(), $GLOBALS['containerBuilder']);

I have followed the installer instructions for Composer which it says I probably didn't do.

EDIT:

This is the autoload.php file. I don't understand less than 50600 as my php version is 8.1?

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {
    echo 'Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for autoloading on PHP <5.6 and you are running '.PHP_VERSION.', please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.'.PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitb16c5397ec4d3651a90c57c257e53aad::getLoader();
```

Comment: "I have tried several installs" - what does that mean? How did you install phpMyAdmin? Also, which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Next time do a `composer diagnose` first.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't help anyone else with this problem. I was able to solve my issue as I had a working setup on another computer and I replaced php.ini,the apache httpd conf file, and the whole of the phpmyadmin file. I replaced the phpmyadmin file first, followed by the php.ini file. It still didn't work but it was reporting a different error message. I didn't save what that was however. I just replaced the apache conf file and then the whole thing worked. So I'm not sure what the problem was exactly.

Comment: If you don't know which of these steps (or which of the configuration lines) resolved the problem, this answer is pretty useless.